# CPAN module installation problems

Tags: perl, cpan, cpanm

I have installed cpan module by `cpan install semantics3` and `cpanm install semantics3` but still it is throwing error like this

> `Can't locate Net/Semantics3.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Net::Semantics3 module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at extraction.pl line 1.`
>
> `BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at extraction.pl line 1.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the whole module name for installation, not just the last part. Thus, your command should be

```
cpan Net::Semantics3
```

instead of just `install semantics3`.

Comment: Actually that will install two modules called "Net::Semantics3" and "install". (Yes, there is a module called "install".) The usual way to install just "Net::Semantics3" is `cpan Net::Semantics3`.

Comment: Completely forgot that the standard cpan command isn't aliased like mine is!

Answer (score 0):

From its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Semantics3/semantics3-perl), you can try:

```
perl -MCPAN -e "install Net::Semantics3"
```